# Make second level collection part of a navigation stack in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a second CollectionView part of a Navigation stack, but cannot get IB to do it. My app has a UINavigationController that uses a UITableViewController that lists Projects to let the user choose a Project. The Project cell has a disclosure indicator that seques to a UICollectionViewController that allows multiple selections.

I've added a "next" BarButton that is supposed to open another collection containing only the selected items and my goal to allow editing each item by bringing up a detail view to edit attributes, and to finally edit the Project attributes and rewind back to the table when done. Here's the Hierarchy:

```
UINavigationController
 Project Table
 ..Collection Select multiple items from Global set
 ....Collection of chosen items (each editable)
 ......Edit Panel for One item (has Back button)
 ......Edit Panel for misc. Project attrs (Done button rewinds to table)
```

The problem is that I can add the first collection from the table and it has a navigation bar and works as expected, but when I add the second collection, I can't add a Navigation Item or Navigation Bar, and when I seque it covers the screen and has no Navigation Bar and isn't connected to the previous view's navigation stack.

I looked around in Apple's sample code and I see that the [SamplePhotoApp](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575/) does something like this, but when I try mimic their approach by adding a NavigationItem, it either becomes invisible or is drawn as a separate view in the Storyboard. When I run the app I am unable to the find the object anywhere in the UI hierarchy using reveal, even though it is clearly in the storyboard. It just isn't connected to anything, nor can I find a way to hook it up.

So, how do I extend my Navigation Stack past the first collection view?

**THUS FAR**: For a workaround I've inserted a regular ViewController in place of the collection, added a NavigationItem and a ContainerView. The segue to the collection now points to the new ViewController, and the default embed segue has been pointed at the old CollectionViewController and the dummy view that IB added was thrown away. I need to put some code in to pass the data via the new ViewController using self.childViewControllers and I no longer get the nice layout defaults, but this looks like it solves the problem of getting from the first collection to the second collection. I still have to patch around things, and finish the rest of the navigation stack for the two edit panels, and figure out how to do rewinding all the way back in case it doesn't work, so a real solution using IB would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to above the best answer has been to insert a regular ViewController in place of the collection, added a NavigationItem and a ContainerView. The Container points at my collection and manages the stack using segues in the typical manner. A rewind segue does indeed rewind back to the view controller as if it were done "normally" so there is nothing special to do there. The one little quirk to be aware of is to be sure to manage the NavBar buttons with an appropriate IBAction, or detect the action that goes through the segue, as one or the other will be called, not both.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are not pushing the second UICollectionView on the Navigation stack.
Please double check that your segue is using "Push" instead of Modal.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to pass the data to the second Collection View and a screen of your Storyboard?

Comment: As for the code, no, there is no code, I'm trying to use IB and none of the code is any different than my explanation. No sure what you're looking for. The screen shot, likewise, would be useless as it shows that the NavigationItem doesn't appear. I'm not sure what information would be revealed by showing a segue pointing at an empty collection view. I've dug deep using the Reveal tool and some custom python debug scripts running in the debugger. IB isn't allowing me to hook it up, just as described. I'll post the screenshot if you insist, but there is nothing there other than I've described.

Comment: If you need something to look at, download the SamplePhotoApp and try to duplicate the "Asset View Controller" in IB. I can't get the NavigationItem into that state. for some reason IB never shows it. That seems to be the crux of the problem.